# Masking systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd

I am installing a few third party rpms in my system, and one of those rpm packages a systemd service file, and a preset file to enable the service.
I want to keep the service disabled and masked.

For disabling, systemd provides [preset framework](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) and I can write a preset file with higher priority.

But how do I mask the service? Is there a configuration file I can install, similar to preset files?
Or I have to add a cron job to run on node reboot to mask the service?

Comment: A generic way of doing it is to write an Ansible playbook which installs packets and then disables and masks unneeded services.

Answer (score 1):

systemctl actually tells you how to do it whenever you mask a service:

```
# systemctl mask foo
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/foo.service → /dev/null.
```

"Masking" a service is similar to the mechanism of *overriding* a service, where unit configuration in `/etc` will take priority over the one in `/usr/lib`. (This is a common pattern in systemd, where local administrator settings in /etc have priority over distribution settings in /usr/lib.)

A service that is overridden with a symlink to `/dev/null` (or with an empty regular file, but symlink is preferred) will be considered "masked" by systemd.